# NSJSONSerialization blank uitableview and null result

Tags: iphone, ios, json

My uitableview is loading fine, however, I'm getting these results and I'm getting blank data on my uitableview. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help. It seems I'm having problems with dictionary or array but I'm confused where to change codes.

This is my json result:

```
{"assistant":[{"assistant":"Joe Black"},{"assistant":"Mary White"}]}
```

Debug results:

```
2013-03-27 15:10:38.132 testJson[3833:c07] its probably a dictionary
2013-03-27 15:10:38.133 testJson[3833:c07] jsonDictionary - (null)
2013-03-27 15:10:38.134 testJson[3833:c07] string is <7b226173 73697374 616e7422
3a5b7b22 61737369 7374616e 74223a22 52696320 446f6e61 746f227d 2c7b2261 73736973
74616e74 223a2252 69632044 6f6e6174 6f227d5d 7d>
2013-03-27 15:10:38.134 testJson[3833:c07] nil
2013-03-27 15:10:38.134 testJson[3833:c07] Is mutable? 1
2013-03-27 15:10:38.135 testJson[3833:c07] Is mutable? 1
2013-03-27 15:10:38.135 testJson[3833:c07] this is your datesArray (
)
```

This my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource> {
NSArray *json;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *json;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

This my .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    kLatestKivaLoansURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

});

}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

NSError* error;    

self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions
error:&error];

if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its an array!");
    NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)json;
    NSLog(@"jsonArray - %@",jsonArray);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"its probably a dictionary");
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)json;
    NSLog(@"jsonDictionary - %@",jsonDictionary);
}

NSLog(@"string is %@", responseData);
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its an array");
}
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its a dictionary");
}
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its a string");
}
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its a number");
}
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its a null");
}
if (json == nil){
    NSLog(@"nil");
}
NSError *parseError;
NSMutableArray *listOfObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[@"[]"
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
error:&parseError];
NSLog(@"Is mutable? %hhi", [listOfObjects isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]);

listOfObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[@"[[],{}]"  
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
error:&parseError];
NSLog(@"Is mutable? %hhi", [listOfObjects isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]);


NSMutableArray *datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *tempDict in json){
    [datesArray addObject:[tempDict objectForKey:@"assistant"]];

        }


NSLog(@"this is your datesArray %@", datesArray);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return self.json.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"assistant"];

return cell;

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Is there anything stored in `error` after you call `JSONObjectWithData:`?

Comment: no. that's all i got from debug window.

Comment: add a line like `NSLog(@"error: %@", error");` after the call.

Comment: I got this, error: (null)

Answer (score 1):

What is self.json? you assign it then you're doing checks on it then you treat it as an array here.

```
[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"assistant"]
```

If you want it to be an array then make an array, check that the returned json is an array, set your array to the json array and use your array in your tableview.

Below is an example of how I handle this, I use my own helper class so ignore that that part but notice how I check if it's an array then I assign it to a NSArray that I have waiting for the data. I then use that NSArray in my TableView and load my data from it.

```
-(void)downloadFinished:(id)sender {

    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[JsonHelper class]]) {

        JsonHelper *jsonHelper = (JsonHelper *)sender;

            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:jsonHelper.receivedData];
            NSDictionary *jsonReturn=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
            NSLog(@"History Return:%@",jsonReturn);

            if ([jsonReturn objectForKey:@"calls"]) {

                if ([[jsonReturn objectForKey:@"calls"]isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

                    historyArray = [jsonReturn objectForKey:@"calls"];
                    NSLog(@"History Array:%@",historyArray);
                    [historyTableView reloadData];

                } else {

                   // Error stuff goes here it was not an array.
                }
            } 
        }
```

In my TableView methods I just reference the the array

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [historyArray count];
}
```

Etc....